# CapacitorJS not showing images

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, capacitor

CapactiorJS won't load images if they are called inside javascript file.

I got a CapacitorJS project which is working fine except that when i tried to call an image file like in example one it dosen't show but example 2 works. Also if i just add the img html tag inside index.html it also shows. I also tried to change the path to "./img/logo.png" also tried to just create the "img" folder inside the public folder but this gets deleted as soon as i run "npm run build". (Of course i know it's possible to use css for this).

EXAMPLE 1: (not working)

```
document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = `<img id="logo_apps" style="width:110px;" src="img/logo.png" />`;
```

EXAMPLE 2: (working)

```
document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = `<img id="logo_apps" style="width:110px;" src="https://google.com/img/logo.png" />`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by importing image like this:

```
import logoImage from '../img/logo.png';
```

and then use logoImage as variable for image path.